# c++ global map available to many objects

Tags: c++, swig

I have a class that needs to be able to look up values in a global stl map object. However, I don't want each class to have a copy since the global object is pretty large. My current implementation is like this:

```
#include obj.h
#include init.h
map <string, vector<float> > gMap;
main() {int argc, char* argv[1]) {
  gMap = init(); // function in init.h that simply creates a map and returns it
  MyObj (); 
}
```

in obj.h, there is an extern to gMap.

I'm curious if there are better ways to accomplish what I want to here. Ideas?

I also plan to export this to Python via SWIG, and this presents a little problem in the current situation (this is some of the motivation for rethinking this). So if any solutions are simple enough to work with minimal problems in SWIG, that would be very good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The best alternative would probably to store the giant map in a std::shared_ptr(or boost::shared_ptr), and then pass it through as a parameter or member to anything that needs it.

```
#include obj.h
#include init.h
#include <memory>
main() {int argc, char* argv[1]) {
  std::shared_ptr<map <string, vector<float> >> gMap; = init(); // function in init.h that simply creates a map and returns it
  MyObj f(gMap); 
}
```

Another solution would be to pass this by reference to anything that needs it. However member references can be quite annoying.

Comment: I thought about that but I don't believe a shared_pointer wraps in SWIG.

Comment: @bid SWIG has support for shared_ptr in `%include <shared_ptr.i>`. You'll need to do `#define SWIG_SHARED_PTR_NAMESPACE std` first if you're using `std::shared_ptr` instead of boost/tr1. Once you've done that you can use the `SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS` macro.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can use initializer lists to achieve this. If the `init` function uses some constant values to initialize the map, then instead of creating it in the `init` function, you can just use this feature:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::map<std::string, std::vector<float>> gMap = {  
    {"foo", {1.5, 1.2, 6.4}},
    {"bar", {1.5, 1.2, 6.1}}
};

int main() {
    use_gmap(gMap);
}
```

Comment: This unfortuantely doesn't work well for me either, since the vectors in the map are so large that it isn't really feasible to explicitly declare them like that.